# Kendo valueAxis not able to retrieve majorUnit

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I want to retrieve majorUnit for valueAxis which throwing error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'majorUnit' of undefined

Code:

```
valueAxis: {
    name: "valueAxis1",
},

render: function (e) {
     var a1 = e.sender.getAxis("valueAxis1").options.majorUnit;
}
```

Error Message:

[image]

When I debuted then I found options are not available.[image]

But same I did with stand alone project in notepad then things are working and able to retrieve majorUnit.

When I am trying following code in notepad then it works and able to get options.

[Link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/various/configure-major-lines-in-value-axis)

This code I also tried:

```
var a2 = e.sender.options.valueAxis.majorUnit
```

but it returns undefined.

screenshot:[image]

Comment: Can you paste here the full options object? I tested your original code, `e.sender.getAxis("valueAxis1").options.majorUnit`, and it worked fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

See if this suits your needs:

```
render: function (e) {
     var a1 = e.sender.options.valueAxis.majorUnit;
}
```

Comment: @Sahi...no this is also not working...it returns ....undefined...screenshot attached above...

Comment: Did you define a `majorUnit` under `valueAxis` in the `Kendo Chart`'s options object? If you didn't, it will be undefined...

Comment: no, I not defined majorUnit. I want to retrieve majorUnit which is provided by kendo itself. If I will define this here it will take form my defined value but I need the value defined by kendo.